# Read array of unknown objects in REST service

Tags: java, rest, cxf

How do i write a REST service for below data POST request? templates can have any data, basically array of data.

```
{
   "name":"Jose",
   "surname":"John",
   "templates":[
      {
         "template1":"333",
         "any":"any"
      },
      {
         "anything":"anything",
         "test":"tafsasdf"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: How do you receive json on server part? As string, or as object? Which libs are you using?

Comment: Please provide more information about the technologies you use.  Also, and that is very important, tell us what you have tried and if you are stuck tell us where.

Answer (score 0):

`CXF` knows how to convert such string to a nested `Map<String, Object>`. You need to have the `jackson` libraries in your classpath and annotate your server method with `@RequestBody`.

Something like this:

```
@RequestBody
public void someMethod(Map<String, Object> json objects) { 
    // Code here
}
```